# Can I use the same html for two components in Angular

Tags: angularjs, controller, components

I have an interesting dilemma, I've written a project that at one point had two controllers and two templates

```
.state('resources',
    {
        url: '/resources',
        controller: 'resourcesController',
        controllerAs: 'resourcesController',
        templateUrl: '/app/pages/resources/resources.view.html',
     })
.state('packages',
    {
        url: '/packages',
        controller: 'packagesController',
        controllerAs: 'packagesController',
        templateUrl: '/app/pages/packages/packages.view.html',
     })
```

After some time, it was apparent that the packages.view.html and the resources.view.html were almost identical, and I am spending a chunk of time copy pasting between the two..

The Controllers are quite different, and of course within resources.view.html, I refer to:

```
<button ng-click="resourcesController.fireButton()">Click me</button>
```

and in packages.view.html

```
<button ng-click="packagesController.fireButton()">Click me</button>
```

Now, before, back in good ole Angular 1.3, I'd have used $scope in each controller, and could declare the same html.. but now? is it even possible?

I ask because I'm about to include a third controller/template, and want to avoid writing and changing three templates.

p.s. I think I could, **if I had the budget/hours/time**, refactor into a sub-component and pass all the data to it, so that's ***not*** going to be a valid answer.
(yet if the only solution takes more time, then I'll present that to my manager)

Comment: Honestly, it seems to me that a hybrid solution (shared view, not shared controller) would be even more confusing to an outsiders perspective than simply two different controllers/views. I think you present your manager with letting it stay as is, or to give you a chance to refactor. If they are as similar as you say, it shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: Its mostly that each time a change comes down the line, I have to change two, and soon three templates each time.. thought I could simply point all three states to the same template and be done.. but since they all have their own controller label.. Argh!

Comment: Yeah, I did some googling and couldn't find anything that looked easy. It seemed like there was an option about dynamically generating the controller, but....I bet it would be time better spent refactoring. Good luck if that is the path you take!

Comment: So, I did some testing on this, mini personal project, dropped all three controller As and used scope on the one template.. worked like a dream.. Each controller loads its own data, sets up its own structure and passes the data into the template, which populates it, regardless of which page.. 

One template 3 controllers..

Wondering if that was the initial intention to $scope & angular?